# font changes in http and https

Tags: http, https

My site shows different different fonts for http and https . It is a wordpress web site . Please help me to  solve the issue. Please check the site [here](http://dreamslandlive.com/Home/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked your site, but I would suspect some of the fonts are loaded externally using plain `http://` links. Those resources wouldn't be loaded when your pages are served over HTTPS (mixed content), so your site would fall back on other fonts.